# VOLVO V50 IMMOBILIZER PROBLEMS CRANK BUT NO FIRE

Tags: troubleshooting

VOLVO V50 2006 2.0 DIESEL SE 
IMMOBILISER MESSAGE NON START.
engine cranking over but no fire ...tried all the hocus pocus  lock 5 x  making alarm go off etc .. cleaned and inspected cem. new battery fitted new starter fitted . n battery in key fob ..now i'm about to embark on new antenna ring can anyone point me in further direction ? assuming the ring makes no difference!!!
my coder reader says dc/dc convertur status low, no other codes
could i have a ecu problem? if so what would be the symtoms?
Please help .its beginning to do my head in !!
Thanks

Comment: DID YOU READ THE CODES?

Comment: no other code other than the one i listed.     i'm only using a autel coder reader ,i suspect volvo would have a better one than i !!  but charge a ransom for just diagnosis and the hassle of getting on a dolly and dragging it to them.